# How to write a generic function to print begin and end iterator elements

Tags: c++, types, iterator

The function below, printloop, is able to print the elements in a collection as below.  But if I try to remove the loop and use std::copy, how do I get that version, print, to work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

// this print function doesn't compile
template <typename iter>
void print(iter begin, iter end) {
  std::copy(begin, end, 
     std::ostream_iterator< what type? >(std::cout, "\t"));
}

template <typename iter>
void printloop(iter begin, iter end) {
    while (begin != end) {
        std::cout << *begin << '\t';
        begin++;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec {1,2,3,4,5};
    printloop(vec.begin(), vec.end());  // works ok
    print(vec.begin(), vec.end()); // how to get working?
}
```

Comment: `typename iter::value_type` or `decltype(*begin)` are two options that come to mind. What were your own attempts?

Comment: For my tastes, I'd rather pass a container.

Comment: This code isn't limited to printing "the elements in a collection"; it prints the elements in a **sequence**. A collection is one way of creating a sequence, but it is not the only way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use [`iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits):

```
template <typename iter>
void print(iter begin, iter end) {
  using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<iter>::value_type;
  std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<value_type >(std::cout, "\t"));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oEP7cWb87)

Answer (score 1):

[`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) to the rescue.

Given an iterator type `iter`, the type being iterated is

```
typename std::iterator_traits<iter>::value_type
```

This solution can work even if the iterator doesn't define `iter::value_type`, such as if the iterator is a raw pointer.

Comment: can you give an example, std::ostream_iterator< std::iterator_traits<iter>::value_type > doesn't work.

Comment: @AngusComber: dependent type, so you have to add `typename`

Comment: @AngusComber you must prefix `typename`, as in `typename std::iterator_traits<iter>::value_type`.